# An interactive guide for web page elements?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, documentation, usability

[pageguide.js](http://tracelytics.github.com/pageguide/) shows usage help about web page's elements by overlaying help balloons over the page. The concept is great, but pageguide.js doesn't support IE8, is hard to customize (eg. font sizes), and a little slow.

Is there anything similar, that would work better, especially on IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/, might be helpful.

Demo link: http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/

Dowload link: http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/WebsiteTour.zip

That is a demo of how to create a website tour or walkthrough with jQuery. If you start the tour, you will see tooltips in each step, explaining a certain part of the website.

Comment: Could you please also add the relevant info here on SO instead of just a link? If the link goes down your answer only contains a not working link. Thanks.

Comment: @dev , peehaa again link only answer